# Child process does not print anything

Tags: c, string, url, fork, wait

This is a simple c program for cutting a url (of the form `www.blabla.com/blabla/..`) into host part and path part. I'm `fork`ing a process to do the job but the child doesn't print enything on the screen. Here's the code.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<string.h>
#include<sys/types.h>
#include<sys/wait.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<errno.h>
#include<unistd.h>

main()
{
   pid_t pid;
   char url[300];
   char* path;
   char* host;
   int n,status;

   printf("Give me a url.\n");
   scanf("%s",url);

   pid=fork();
   if (pid==0)
   {
      path=strchr(url, '/');
      n=strlen(url)-strlen(path);
      strncpy(host,url,n);
      printf("path : %s \nhost : %s\n", path,host);
      sleep(3);
      exit(status);

   }
   else
   {
      wait(&status);
   }
   printf("Bye!\n");
 }
```

I know that the url parsing is weak but that's not the issue here. I don't understand why the code of child process doesnt execute. If i change the code of the child (except sleep and wait) into something else (simple like printing hello world) everything works. In addition the code for parsing url is working fine without calling a child to do the job.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I spot two issues in your code.

1. Where did you allocate memory for `host`? without that, its undefined behaviour.
2. `strncpy()` is very unreliable. use of `strcpy()` is preferred.

Change your code to allocate memory before copying.

```
path=strchr(url, '/');
n=strlen(url)-strlen(path);
host = calloc (n, sizeof (char));   //memory allocation
strcpy(host,url);                   //use strcpy
```

---

EDIT:

However, neither `strcpy()` not `strncpy()` is completely safe. To be on safer side, i prefer using `strcat()` to achieve the same.

```
host[0] = '\0';
strncat(host, url, n);
```

- null termination is guranteed.
- can control the length to be copied using `n`.

Please check the below code

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<string.h>
#include<sys/types.h>
#include<sys/wait.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<errno.h>
#include<unistd.h>

main()
{
   pid_t pid;
   char url[300];
   char* path;
   char* host;
   int n,status;

   printf("Give me a url.\n");
   scanf("%s",url);

   pid=fork();
   if (pid==0)
   {
      path=strchr(url, '/');
      n=strlen(url)-strlen(path);
      host = calloc (n, sizeof (char));     
        host[0] = '\0';
        strncat(host, url, n);
      printf("path : %s \nhost : %s\n", path,host);
      sleep(3);
      exit(status);

   }
   else
   {
      wait(&status);
   }
   printf("Bye!\n");
 }
```

Samele i/o:

```
[sourav@broadsword temp]$ ./a.out 
Give me a url.
www.blabla.com/blabla/abc/def
path : /blabla/abc/def 
host : www.blabla.com
Bye!
[sourav@broadsword temp]$
```

Comment: why is `strncpy` unreliable?  Isn't it safer than `strcpy`?

Comment: @SSC there are lot of reasons. mostly it is unsafe, because, if the supplied buffer length and the `n` value are same, then there will be no terminating null `\0` to indicate end-of-string. you can check the same [here](http://linux.die.net/man/3/strncpy).

Comment: @ Sourav Ghosh Thank you for your help.It seems that this is the problem. I changed my code as you say but strcpy copies entire url to host instead of the first n elements. Instead, if i use strncpy, it works fine.

Comment: @mort32 well, in that case, you can use `strncpy()`, but i personally prefer neither. I'll add a line to my answer to update regarding this.